# Panda, missing parameters to read a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

We receive a .csv file daily, via a python script. We know that Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.10 recognizes, reads, and will import the data manually into a table without issue.  However, we need to automate this import with Python (3.9).  We are able to connect to the MS SQL DataBase using pyodbc (4.0.32) and browse the table.  Several attempts have been made using CVS or PANDAS libraries to read the CSV file and load the data into a DataFrame without success.

Most recent tries result in an "Empty DataFrame" (see OUTOUT below).  As noted in the output, there are 0 rows and 18,000+ columns. Note: the data in the CSV file is a very long single line of data, with "\n" for new line terminator.  Three sample data rows are present for reference, identifying data has been removed and replaced with “XXXXXXXXX”.

We have also included the function that reads the .csv file and returns the DataFrame we wish to import.

Any assistance in crafting the appropriate pandas.read_csv() parameters would be gratefully appreciated.

DataFrame Maker Function:

```
def mk_df():
    csv_file_nm = 'data_file.csv'
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_nm, sep=',', lineterminator='\n', engine='c', keep_default_na=False)
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print("The DataFrame is: ", data_frame)
    return data_frame
```

Output:

```
The DataFrame is:  Empty DataFrame

DATA:
Columns: [b'source-domain, asset-id, asset-type, value, vee-value, unit-of-measure, channel, start-date-time, end-date-time, flow-direction\nXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXX, METER, 0.6336, 0.6336.1, KWH_USAGE, 1, 2021-12-01T06:00:00.000+0000, 2021-12-01T07:00:00.000+0000, FORWARD\nXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXX, METER, 0.5184, 0.5184.1, KWH_USAGE.1, 1.1, 2021-12-01T07:00:00.000+0000.1, 2021-12-01T08:00:00.000+0000, FORWARD\nXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXX, METER, 0.3456, 0.3456.1, KWH_USAGE.2, 1.2, 2021-12-01T08:00:00.000+0000.1, 2021-12-01T09:00:00.000+0000, FORWARD\n <snip>

[0 rows x 18370 columns]
```

Comment: Try changing your `sep` to `, ` (instead of `,`).

Comment: Maybe try changing your `lineterminator` to `\\n` (i.e. with the `\` escaped)

Comment: Can you post some example rows of `data_file.csv`?

Comment: The .csv is read as 8bit octets (notice the b in front of the string). Pandas can't find the letters in the string, because ',' is not b',' (that's also a problem for every other letter). You can try the `encoding` parameter, but I doubt that would work.

Comment: Is the newline terminator `\n` in wich case your data would appear in an editor as individual lines or is in `\\n` in wihch case you might have one giant line with what looks like "\" in it

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with `pandas 1.1.5`. I used the first two rows of your example string and saved them as bytes. Then imported with `read_csv` and your parameters. `pandas` read the file correct (except that the columns have a leading space, but that was expected)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions, they were very helpful in understanding and resolving our issues.  Our resolution to the issue of the very long (single line) byte-string was, while receive the data from the source, to read the results into a Pandas data-frame first, THEN to write it out to a CSV file.  Our data now is not a byte-string and is 10 columns and 18000++ rows.